# Plot infinite series

Tags: pgfplots, diagrams

I want to draw a function defined as infinite serie using pgfplots. Is that possible and how?
The function is given by

```
\[u(t,x)=\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}\frac{\sin(2nt)\sin(nx)}{n^2}.\]
```

One can  give `t` some fixed values say `t=0.1, 0.2, 1, 4`, and try to draw the function of `x` only, but still blocked with the infinite sum.

In fact, what i can do is working with single function, say if n=2 or 3 or any fixed value in N. But with infinite sum i have no idea.
Here is a mwe.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor,pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
\addplot3 [surf,domain=0:pi,domain y=0:1] {sin(4*deg(y))*sin(2*deg(x))/4};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
axis lines=center,
enlargelimits=true,]
\addplot[thick, red, domain=0:pi, smooth, samples=300]  {sin(4)*sin(2*deg(x))/4};
\addplot[thick, green ,domain=0:pi, smooth, samples=300]  {sin(8)*sin(2*deg(x))/4};
\addplot[thick, blue, domain=0:pi, smooth, samples=300]  {sin(12)*sin(2*deg(x))/4};
\legend{$t=1$,  $t=2$, $t=3$};  
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You should provide more information over what you have attempted and what your code looks like i.e. edit it into your question, putting a function and asking for it to be done for you isn't how this site works. It is fine if your code doesn't work or your attempts aren't substantial but you are asking people to do everything for you including basic stuff like the `\documentclass`, help people help you please

Comment: @JamesT OK. will try, thanks.

Comment: @JamesT any idea please.

Comment: I am not sure how to solve this but someone will definately be able to help with this soon, lots of experts on this topic, thanks for including code it makes all the difference :)

Comment: @JamesT OK. Thanks for the interest.

Comment: You can not draw infinite sum but only some approximation of it.

Comment: @Zarko Any help will be  appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can approximate the infinite series by truncating it at a certain number of terms. In practice, you should choose a reasonably high number of terms to get a good approximation. In this case, I will show you how to truncate the series at 10 terms. You can easily adjust the number of terms to your needs.

To make your code more concise, you can use a loop to generate the terms in the sum. Here's an example using your function with t=0.1, 0.2, 1, and 4:

```
\documentclass[margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\RepeatFunction}{mm}{\int_step_function:nnN{#1}{#2}\RepeatFunction:n}
\pgfplotsset{repeatable~function/.code=\DeclareExpandableDocumentCommand{\RepeatFunction:n}{m}{#1}}
\ExplSyntaxOff
\pgfplotsset{
    /pgf/declare function={sinsin(\n,\t,\x)=sin(2*\n*\t)*sin(\n*\x)/(\n*\n);},
    repeatable function={+sinsin(#1,\t,x)},
    sinsin terms/.initial=10,
    sinsin terms/.code={\pgfplotsset{sinsin terms/.initial=#1}}
}

\begin{document}
    \foreach \t in {0.1, 0.2, 1, 4}{
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            \begin{axis}[
                trig format plots=rad,
                axis lines=center,
                enlargelimits,
                xtick = {0, pi/4, pi/2, 3*pi/4, pi},
                xticklabels = {0, $\pi/4$, $\pi/2$, $3\pi/4$, $\pi$},
                domain=0:pi,
                samples=201,
                no marks,
                title={t = $\t$},
                legend pos={outer north east},
                sinsin terms=10 % Set the number of terms here
                ]
                \addplot[blue] {\RepeatFunction{1}{\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/sinsin terms}}};
            \end{axis}
        \end{tikzpicture}
    }
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This look good, i will try understand it. I need one plot (the sum function) by axis.

Comment: It doesn't seem to sum the terms, it only draw them one by one.

Comment: you are sure. I stole a piece of code from Qrrbrbirlbel and edited it the answer

Comment: Thanks again. I'll try it.

Answer (score 5):

This infinite sum is very slowly convergent because you expect an absolute error of order `1/N` if using `N` terms.  This means roughly that if you want one more decimal, you need ten times as many terms.  For graphics assuming `1` maps to say `1cm`, you should aim at a precision of say `0.1mm`, knowing though that the final plot if continuous will apply some interpolation using Bézier curves (using straight segments will display visible slope changes).  This means (I have not estimated too seriously) you will start this knowing you need about 100 terms.  As implied constant matters, perhaps 20 terms will be about enough.  Then, mind the numerical precision of the computations.

As explained in other answers it seems you need to do some work with TikZ and there is no simple syntax of the type `add(sin(2n*t)sin(n*x)/n^2, n from 1 to N)`.

I have been pointed out by some colleague from the back office department who had some degree in string theory that you can express by an exact formula the sum, in this case (apparently mathematicians are not always able to do so).  First of all `u(t,x) = (v(2t-x)-v(2t+x))/2` with

```tex
v(y) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\cos(n y)}{n^2}
```

[It is known](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli_polynomials#Fourier_series) that `v(2\pi u)` is up to a factor the one-periodic function which on interval `[0,1]` has value `B_2(u)` where `B_2` is the second Bernoulli polynomial, `B_2(u) = u^2 - u + 1/6`.  Precisely

```tex
\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\cos(2\pi n u)}{n^2} = \pi^2B_2(\{u\})
```

where `\{u\}` is the fractional part.  This is actually one of the well-known proofs based on Fourier series of Euler evaluation of `\sum 1/n^2 = \pi^2/6` as we see by plugging-in `u=0`.

[image]

To sum up

```
\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\sin(2n t)\sin(nx)}{n^2} =
\frac{\pi^2}2\left(B_2(\{\frac{2t-x}{2\pi}\})-
  B_2(\{\frac{2t+x}{2\pi}\})\right)
```

[image: sum of trigonometric series]

The left hand-side is `\pi`-periodic in `t` and `2\pi`-periodic in `x` and odd.  So I will assume `0<x<\pi` and `0<t<\pi`.  Also let `x'=x/2\pi` so that `0<x'<1/2` and `t' = t/2\pi`. I will simplify here for comparing with the plots in other pictures and assume not only `0<t'<1/2` but `0<t'<1/4` so `0<2t'+x' < 1` and the second contribution with `B_2` is `B_2(2t'+x')`. (one can use oddness in `t` to always reduce to this case `0<t<\pi/2`). So

- `0<x'<2t'<1/2`: we get `(2t'-x')^2 - (2t'-x') + 1/6 - (x'+2t')^2 + (x'+2t') - 1/6 = -8x't'+2x' = (2 - 8t') x'` and let's not forget the multiplicative factor `\pi^2/2`.  Hence a linear growth reaching the value `2\pi^2(1 - 4t')t'` at `x'=2t'`. As `t'=t/2\pi`, this is `t(\pi - 2t)`.  For example for `t=0.1` we get `0.294159...`.  Hopefully I got those computations right, will correct and repent if not later on, but this is reaching beyond my TeX knowledge here.
- `2t'<x'<1/2`: now `2t'-x'<0` so we use evenness of `B_2(\{u\})` and replace it with `x'-2t'` so that can apply the formula and we get (up to the `\pi^2/2`: `(x'-2t')^2 - (x'-2t') + 1/6 - (x'+2t')^2 + (x'+2t') - 1/6 = -8t'x' +4t' = 4t'(1 - 2x')` which is linear decrease towards value `0` at `x'= 0.5` and starts for `x'=2t'` at `4t'(1-4t')` (times `\pi^2/2`, so `t(\pi-2t)` which (at it should) is same value as found before.

So we can explain the exact shape of the limit graph with infinitely many terms: it is on `(0,\pi)` (for `t<\pi/2`) composed of two straight segments joining at the point with Cartesian coordinates `(2t,(\pi - 2t)t` and being with zero ordinate at `x=0` and `x=\pi`.  I tried to reconstitute from my Physics Ph.D. colleagues hastened explications, so don't use this for homework without independent counseling.

[image: value of maximum is t(pi-2t)]

Comment: Thanks for all the details.

Answer (score 4):

As the others have said, no, you can't calculate an inifinite sum.

However, you can calculate a sum up to a specific point.

The macro `\RepeatFunction{s}{e}` should help you here. It simply repeats a given function for all integer values *n* between `s` and `e`.

The function it should use can be specified by using `repeatable function` where `#1` stands for the value *n*.

Since your function is also parametrized, I also added a `sinsin t` value-key which is used by the repeatable function.

If you only want to plot this function once (for a given *t*) you will need to figure out yourself at which *n* to stop.

### Code

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
\usepgfplotslibrary{groupplots}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\RepeatFunction}{mm}{\int_step_function:nnN{#1}{#2}\RepeatFunction:n}
\pgfplotsset{repeatable~function/.code=\DeclareExpandableDocumentCommand{\RepeatFunction:n}{m}{#1}}
\ExplSyntaxOff
\pgfplotsset{
  /pgf/declare function={sinsin(\n,\t,\x)=sin(2*\n*\t)*sin(\n*\x)/(\n*\n);},
  repeatable function={+sinsin(#1,\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/sinsin t},x)},
  sinsin t/.initial=1}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
  mini legend/.style={at={(rel axis cs:.5,0)}, above, node contents={$t = #1$}}]
\begin{groupplot}[
  group style={group size = 2 by 2},
  %
  trig format plots=rad, axis lines=center, enlargelimits,
  xtick = {0, pi/4, pi/2, 3*pi/4, pi},
  xticklabels = {0, $\pi/4$, $\pi/2$, $3\pi/4$, $\pi$},
  domain=0:pi, samples=129, no marks,
  every axis legend/.append style={
    at={(1,1)}, anchor=north west, path only,
    /tikz/column 2/.append style={anchor=west}},
  style 10+/.style={path only},
  style 10/.style={thick, densely dashed, black}
]
\nextgroupplot
  \pgfplotsinvokeforeach{1,...,5,10}{
    \addplot+[style #1+/.try, forget plot, very thin] {sinsin(#1,1,x)};
    \addplot+[style #1/.try] {\RepeatFunction{1}{#1}};
  }
  \node[mini legend=1];
\nextgroupplot[sinsin t=2]
  \pgfplotsinvokeforeach{1,...,5,10}{
    \addplot+[style #1+/.try, forget plot, very thin] {sinsin(#1,2,x)};
    \addplot+[style #1/.try] {\RepeatFunction{1}{#1}};
    \addlegendentry{$n = #1$}
  }
  \node[mini legend=2];
\nextgroupplot[sinsin t=.2]
  \pgfplotsinvokeforeach{1,...,5,10}{
    \addplot+[style #1+/.try, forget plot, very thin] {sinsin(#1,.2,x)};
    \addplot+[style #1/.try] {\RepeatFunction{1}{#1}};
  }
  \node[mini legend=0.2];
\nextgroupplot[sinsin t=.5]
  \pgfplotsinvokeforeach{1,...,5,10}{
    \addplot+[style #1+/.try, forget plot, very thin] {sinsin(#1,.5,x)};
    \addplot+[style #1/.try] {\RepeatFunction{1}{#1}};
  }
  \node[mini legend=0.5];
\end{groupplot}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

Comment: It should be noted, if there's a function this inifinite sum converges to that one can be plotted probably much easier and faster. But TeX can't be used to find this function. (And for a given *t*, even WolframAlpha doesn't produce something usable.) It appears these sums converge to (two sides of) a rounded triangle.

Comment: This look good. i'll try it. Thanks

Comment: @studentmaths No problem. Don't forget that there's also ways to evaluate these functions with another software (in some cases directly from your document) and then just import the values and let PGFPlots draw it. This can change speed and precision. (Though, the `external` library can help with the former.)

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel the graph is `(0,0)--(2t,t(π-2t))--(π,0)` if `0<t<π/2` hence a straight triangle, then the rest is obtained by oddness in `x` and `2π`-periodicity.  Up to changing `t` into `-t` which translates into taking mirror symmetry in horizontal axis, one can always reduce to this case.  But these mathematical details are secondary to the elements of your answer and others which are what will prove useful to visitors, not the mathematical result of my answer.

Answer (score 3):

- You can not draw infinite sum but only some approximation of it.
- `tikz` and `pgfšplots` packages have not defined command for calculation of sum of functions.
- From given equation, considering only first four terms, a possible MWE is:

```
\documentclass[margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    trig format plots=rad,  % <- ----
    axis lines=center,
    enlargelimits,
    xtick = {0, pi/4, pi/2, 3*pi/4, pi},
    xticklabels = {0, $\pi/4$, $\pi/2$, $3\pi/4$, $\pi$},
    domain=0:pi,
    samples=201,
    no marks,
%
    legend pos={outer north east}
]
\addplot    {sin(1*x)*sin((1^2)*x)/(1^2)
             + sin(2*x)*sin((2^2)*x)/(2^2)
             + sin(3*x)*sin((3^2)*x)/(3^2)
             + sin(4*x)*sin((4^2)*x)/(4^2)
             + sin(5*x)*sin((5^2)*x)/(5^2)
            };
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. I think the question is how to get a good approximation.

Comment: @studentmaths, and what is good approximation for you? BTW, you can add more terms ito `\addplot`.

Comment: Yes! not sure yet!

Answer (score 3):

I found your question difficult to interpret so I need to explain my approach a bit more. First, your question is "I want to draw a function defined as infinite serie[s] using pgfplots. Is that possible and how?". The answer, as Zarko indicated will necessarily involve a finite number of terms. It won't be exact.
So I will explain how to plot 1 infinite series, under the assumption that `t=.1`.

When you are getting into more complicated mathematics, it's important to be aware that the accuracy of your calculations and plots might not be correct; `pgfplots` is not a computer algebra system (CAS), after all. I find it helpful to first determine what the answer should be using a CAS. After that, use the sagetex package to incorporate the CAS plots/calculations into your LaTeX document. You talked about fixing a value of `t` first, so I picked `t=.1` and went to a [Sage Cell Server](https://sagecell.sagemath.org/) where you can copy/paste the following code:

```
def f(t,n):
     return (sin(2*n*t)*sin(n*x))/(n^2)

g(x)=sum(f(.1,n) for n in range(1,21))
h(x)=sum(f(.1,n) for n in range(1,201))
P1=plot(g(x),(x,0,3.14))
P2=plot(h(x),(x,0,3.14),color="red")
(P1+P2).show()
```

Press the `Enter` button and you'll get the output below:

[image]

From this output, I see that graphing 20 terms of the series gives me a pretty good estimate, which is what I'll use in my LaTeX document. You should experiment to find the value of `n` that you think works best. Why did I say 20 terms? Because `range(1,21)` is Python and it doesn't run that last value, so the plot I'm using sums up the first 20 terms. Notice also that I have defined f(t,n) in general. You will be able to easily change `t` to whatever you want. What we want `pgfplots` to plot now is `g(x)` but since we can't trust the numerical accuracy of this for complicated math, we will use the [sagetex](https://ctan.org/pkg/sagetex?lang=en) to link the Sage CAS calculations to our document. The code is below:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{sagetex,xcolor,pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
\begin{document}
\begin{sagesilent}
def f(t,n):
     return (sin(2*n*t)*sin(n*x))/(n^2)

g(x)=sum(f(.1,n) for n in range(1,21))

x_coords = [x for x in srange(0,6.28,.01)]
y_coords = [g(x).n(digits=4) for x in x_coords]
output = r"\begin{tikzpicture}"
output += r"\begin{axis}[xmin=0,xmax=6.28,ymin= -.5,ymax=.5,"
output += r"xlabel=$x$,ylabel=$y$,axis x line=middle,axis y line=middle,"
output += r"grid style=dashed]"
output += r"\addplot[thin, blue] coordinates {"
for i in range(0,len(x_coords)-1):
    output += r"(%f , %f) "%(x_coords[i],y_coords[i])
output += r"};"
output += r"\end{axis}"
output += r"\end{tikzpicture}"
\end{sagesilent}
\sagestr{output}
\end{document}
```

The output, running in Cocalc, is shown below:

[image]

Note, I changed the graph so that it goes about 2pi (about 6.28). The
line `x_coords = [x for x in srange(0,6.28,.01)]` is going to set the x-values to be plotted as 0, .01, ...., 6.27. The line `y_coords = [g(x).n(digits=4) for x in x_coords]` says, to calculate g(x) for each x-value, but we force the answer to be a decimal (with 4 significant figures) so that pgfplots can handle it. Notice that using `Sage` along with `sagetex` lets you avoid typing out the 20 terms in sin(2(1)(.1))*sin((1)x))/(1^2)+....+sin(2(20)(.1))*sin((20)x))/(20^2). Finally, it may seem odd to insert the code as a raw string; that's done because processing the document is, behind the scenes, a 3 step process: first, the LaTeX code must run as is, then the Python/Sage code must run without error and then the document is processed 1 more time to put the Python/Sage output into the LaTeX document. Without strings it's more likely the code will not run under LaTex during the first pass.

[Sage](https://www.sagemath.org/) is a free CAS which is not part of LaTeX. You can download it to your computer and get it to work with LaTeX but the easiest way to get started is to open a free [Cocalc](https://cocalc.com/) account, create a LaTeX document there, copy/paste the code in and press `Build`.

Comment: Thanks. I'll give it a try